# How do I get the non-mobile version of a Google site?

Tags: google-sites

When I view my "new" google site on a desktop, I can see the content fill the entire page.

When I view the same site on mobile, the layout is distorted and what used to be rows become columns.

How do I view the desktop version of a Google site on mobile? I tried guessing and adding `?nomobile=1` to the end of the URL, but that didn’t do anything. I couldn’t find any resources on line asking for this either.

I tried hitting the "request desktop page" in mobile Safari to no avail either.